# Symfony Mailer configure sendmail parameters

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-mailer

we are using symfony/mailer in our project and i was wondering how i can configure the sendmail command with custom paramters. i found alot of content referencing to swiftmailer but we do not use that on this project.

we use:

```
symfony/mailer                           v4.4.7             Symfony Mailer Component
```

and i cannot find the configuration for the sendmail command or how that would be configured.
we have to use a specific command for that:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t
```

how would the configuration of symfony/mailer look like to use that specific command?

we cannot use the default

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs
```

because thats no option for our customer in this case...

help is much appreciated

**EDIT:**
we just patched the core for our requirements on that specific project. i leave the question unresolved because their might be a better solution to that?

Comment: you can probably override the defaults in your services.yaml by setting the parameters given to [SendmailTransport](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.1/src/Symfony/Component/Mailer/Transport/SendmailTransport.php) ... and that might already be enough.

Comment: or maybe command https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#command

Comment: ye thats a feature for the "old" swiftmailer which we can not use.  seems like it was a conscious decision to not make the command configurable within symfony/mailer because its actually a bad approach to not use -bs.

Answer (score 0):

SymfonyMailer uses the php.ini configuration, so try again with this:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t
```

Comment: they just set the default/recommended command in class SendmailTransport as attribute, no?